# Input validation for country name in php7

Tags: php, php-7

I am working on a PHP script which takes input from command line. it takes two strings as two country names like

```
- php myphp.php japan china (command line)
```

php code:

```
if(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
    $first = $argv[1];
    $second = $argv[2];
    print_r($argv);
}
```

Here $first and $second are passed to other functions for further processing of the data. Before passing these arguments, I need to check if they are valid country names or not.

But when the country name consists of two strings like south korea, it does not take the whole country name as one input.

```
- php myphp.php japan south korea (command line)

Array
(
    [0] => myphp.php
    [1] => china
    [2] => south
    [3] => korea
)
```

How can i take input of a country which name has two or three strings ? e.g. in the above array, $argv[1] should be 'china' and $argv[2] should be 'south korea'.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Define "country name". Is "United States of America", "America", "United States", "USA" and "US" all valid? Many countries have multiple de-facto names. For example, "South Korea" is not actually a country, it's officially the "Republic of Korea".

Comment: This is why separating the input with a comma or some other kind of delimiter is the best approach. The alternative is to make an extraordinarily ugly regular expression that can tease out matches, something made complicated because several countries have names that are part of other country names, like the "Sudan" vs. "South Sudan".

Comment: Until you have some sort of code you don't really have a Stack Overflow question. This needs to be more technically specific and what you have here is really a long way from a solution, so you'll need to experiment more. I've made some suggestions here worth investigating, but there's other equally valid approaches.

Comment: @tadman, the question is edited again

Comment: This endpoint gives you all the valid country names: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name

Comment: @Arleigh Hix, the question is updated. I am looking for a way to seperate $argv[1] and $argv[2] with comma. let me know if you have any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply enclose the two country names in quotes

```
- php myphp.php 'japan' 'south korea' (command line)
Array
(
    [0] => cli.php
    [1] => japan
    [2] => south korea
)
```

Or if you want to use a comma you need to do some data manipulation in `myphp.php`

```
// concatenate the relevant arguments into one string
$arguments = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < count($argv); $i++) {
  $arguments .= $argv[$i] . ' ';
}
// explode on comma
$arguments = explode(', ', $arguments);

print_r($arguments);
```

Then:

```
- php myphp.php japan, south korea (command line)
Array
(
    [0] => japan
    [1] => south korea
)
```

Comment: Could also be `cli.php japan "south korea"` or `cli.php japan south\ korea` as both methods properly escape the space.